# Unit testing NestJS controller with request

Tags: unit-testing, express, nestjs

My Controller function definition looks like that:
`async login(@Req() request, @Body() loginDto: LoginDto): Promise<any> {`

How I could prepare/mockup Request to provide first argument of function from Jest test? 
Inside funciton I am setting headers using `request.res.set`. Should I somehow pass real Request object to function and then check if header is set or rather mockup whole Request object and check if set function was called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to do that mocking requests and response using `node-mocks-http` library.

```js
const req = mocks.createRequest()
req.res = mocks.createResponse()
```

and then passing this as an argument.

```js
const data = await authController.login(req, loginDto)
expect(req.res.get('AccessToken')).toBe(token.accessToken)
```

Comment: Is it a good (idiomatic) way to do it in NestJS, since it's supposed to be responsible to resolve all the dependecies via injection? I'm just asking because I'm also looking for a way to implement that.

Comment: This is not valid anymore, types have changed and the return type for createRequest() is not compatible to what the controller needs.

Comment: how to do it instead now?

Answer (score 6):

I followed a different approach and instead of using `node-mocks-http` library I used [@golevelup/ts-jest](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/testing), also, instead of testing if the function returns some value, like `res.json()` or `res.status()`, I checked if the function was called with the value I wanted to.

I borrowed this approach from [Kent C. Dodds's testing workshop](https://github.com/kentcdodds/testing-workshop/blob/master/server/src/controllers/__tests__/auth.js), take a look for similar ideas. Anyway, this is what I did in order to `mock` the `Response` dependency of my `Controller's route`:

```js
  // cars.controller.spec.ts
  import { createMock } from '@golevelup/ts-jest';

  const mockResponseObject = () => {
    return createMock<Response>({
      json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    });
  };


  ... ommited for brevity

  it('should return an array of Cars', async () => {
    const response = mockResponseObject();

    jest
      .spyOn(carsService, 'findAll')
      .mockImplementation(jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedCarsList));

    await carsController.getCars(response);

    expect(response.json).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(response.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ cars: mockedCarsList });
    expect(response.status).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(response.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
  });
```

And that's it, I think that the implementation details aren't that important but in any case I'll leave the link to the [Github repo](https://github.com/sigfriedCub1990/cars-api) where you can find the whole project.

Comment: `@golevelup/ts-jest` was created for issues like this

Comment: For reference: [@golevelup/ts-jest](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/testing)